# MongoDB remove() method is undefined with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using PHP7 + mongoDB. PHP driver installed with composer.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$m= new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");

$db = $m->test_database;

$collection = $db->test_table;

$document = array( "first_name" => "Dude", "last_name" => "Dudly" ); 

$collection->insertOne($document);

$cursor = $collection->find();

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    echo $document["first_name"] . "\n";
}

$collection->remove();
?>
```

This prints out "**Dude**" as expected. 
But also the following exception:

**Call to undefined method MongoDB\Collection::remove() in...**

And the inserted data in the collection is not removed.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Collection.php) library, then yes, `Collection` indeed does not have a `remove` method. Why do you think it should? What should it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-deleteOne/), `remove` operation takes query filter for removing documents from collection.</s>

```
$collection->remove($document, array("justOne" => true));// With filter to remove single entry
$collection->remove(array());//Empty filter will remove all the entries from collection.
```

Btw you can use newest driver for php http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

[1](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-deleteOne/): http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php

Update: Didn't realize OP was using composer for MongoDB.

You've to use [`deleteOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-deleteOne/) and [`deleteMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-deleteMany/) variant with latest driver.

```
$deleteResult = $collection->deleteOne(["first_name" => "Dude"]);
```

Comment: Thank You! Awesome answer, You save my day!